# `do` block inside a computation expressions got error?

Tags: f#

The following code can be compiled.

```
async {
    //do (
    use outStream = File.Create(downloading)
    do! httpRequestStreamCopyTo url outStream
    //)
    if File.Exists(fullname) then
        File.Delete(fullname)
    File.Move(downloading, fullname)
}
```

And I will need to close the `outStream` before renaming. So it's changed to

```
async {
    do (
        use outStream = File.Create(downloading)
        do! httpRequestStreamCopyTo url outStream // Error
    )
    if File.Exists(fullname) then
        File.Delete(fullname)
    File.Move(downloading, fullname)
}
```

And it got the following error on `do! httpRequestStreamCopyTo (reportingUri url) outStream`?

> Error FS0750  This construct may only be used within computation expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can await an embedded `async` body like this so that `outStream` is properly scoped:

```fsharp
async {
    do! async {
        use outStream = File.Create(downloading)
        do! httpRequestStreamCopyTo url outStream
    }
    if File.Exists(fullname) then
        File.Delete(fullname)
    File.Move(downloading, fullname)
}
```

Since that embedded body is blocking, this is conceptually equivalent to sequential `async` calls:

```fsharp
async {
    use outStream = File.Create(downloading)
    do! httpRequestStreamCopyTo url outStream
}
async {
    if File.Exists(fullname) then
        File.Delete(fullname)
    File.Move(downloading, fullname)
}
```

Comment: Is there any drawback to nest a lot of `async`?

Comment: While I can't speak to the overhead of nesting `async` calls definitively, I updated my answer with a conceptually identical solution that doesn't nest, yet respects the `use` scope and still blocks in the same way.